# Text messed up when exported as PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, export

When I am exporting this file as PDF the text gets messed up. What causes this and how can I fix it? It's a regular text element and standard pdf presets.

Merging all the layers and rasterising it works, but it's a pain and the PDF exports at 6.1MB which is silly for just a pdf file.

Thank you

[image: Messed up text]

Comment: My first guess would be to check if there are other boxes beneath/above the text one. 
ps. are you using photshop for creating text only pdf?

Comment: It looks as if somehow the text got set to "outlined". Check — maybe 3 times — whether there has been some changes in the text properties; I have read references that under certain circumstances, Indesign changes properties when hovering (if I remember correctly). Or check whether text got copied and placed on top with different properties.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY There is nothing except a white background beneath the text. I am using Photoshop as there is a graphic sidebar next to the text :) Perhaps I should do it in InDesign instead. This bug is truly annoying!

Comment: @MaxWyss The text property is 'regular' and I don't see anything odd about the text properties. Which properties could be off?

Comment: @user18375 I would use Id. A few times photoshop had problem with text while saving to pdf. Usually because some other layers beneath of above messed with it exporting capabilities.

Comment: There is no way to solve this based upon the information which has been provided. It could be a poor file set up, a bad font, bad PDF job options.. there's simply no telling.